# How to manually trigger bootstrap "required" tooltip alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When you submit a form via `<input type="submit">`
 and some input with `required` attribute was empty, a little box appears near to the missing input box saying "Please fill out this field" or something similar (I use it in Italian so I don't know the exact wording used in English).

I need to manually trigger this tooltip alert using JavaScript, any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: thats called validation and theres plenty of libraries and examples out there.

Comment: Assuming you mean the `required` attribute, this is a part of HTML5 so the validation is not necessarily bootstrap related. You should be able to see it by just submitting the form. We need to see your code to help you more effectively.

Comment: I though that was bootstrap related! I'm sorry! Do you know how to manually trigger that control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form validation is provided by HTML5, it's not related with Bootstrap, to disable the default form validation provided by the browser you have to work with the form containing the input, for example using the attribute `novalidate` will disable the default form validation provided by the browser. If then you want to use a custom form validation function you can use the onsubmit event on the form, so for example you will have something like:

```
<form onsubmit='return submitForm(this);' novalidate='novalidate'>
  <input type='text' required>
  <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

By doing this when the form is submitted you are passing the function submitForm the submitted form, so that this function is able to iterate through the elements of the form to check them.
Something like:

```
function submitForm(formToValidate){
   var formValid=true;
   var inputs = formToValidate.getElementsByTagName("input");
   var errorDescription;
   for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
   {
     var inputValid=true;
     switch(inputs[i].type)
     {
        case "number":
            if(inputs[i].hasAttribute("required")&&inputs[i].value=="")
            {
                inputValid=false;
                errorDescription="Required field";
            }
            /*Check other attributes here (max, min, step, etc.)*/
            break;
         /*Check other types of input here*/
     }
     if(!inputValid)
     {
        markInputAsNotValid(inputs[i],errorDescription);
        formValid=false;
        break;
     }
  }
  return formValid;
}
```

Note that the value returned by the function `submitForm` is used by the browser to determine if the submission was successful.

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation